# Reordering matrix multiplications to compute a scalar valued function

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^{K \times D}$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{D \times D}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{K \times K}$. $A$ is a diagonal matrix. How can I find the matrix $B$ in terms of the elements of matrix $A$ that satisfies the following equality:

$\sum_{k=1}^K \theta_{k,:} A \theta_{k,:}^T = \sum_{d=1}^D \theta_{:,d}^T B \theta_{:,d}$,

where $\theta_{k,:}$ is the $k$th row and $\theta_{:,d}$ is the $d$th column of the matrix $\theta$?

Comment: Should it not be $\sum_{d=1}^D \theta_{:,d}^T B \theta_{:,d}$?

Comment: Yes, I corrected it.